# cURL script works when run from one server but not another

Tags: php, curl

I recently moved a cURL script from one server (Ubuntu) to another (Mac OS X). The script worked when run from the Ubuntu server but it doesn't work on the OS X server. I get error 35 and this:

```
error:14077417:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert illegal parameter
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Here's what's probably a really good clue. This doesn't work:

```
curl -v https://foo.com/OA_HTML/RF.jsp?function_id=123
```

But this does:

```
curl -v -sslv3 https://foo.com/OA_HTML/RF.jsp?function_id=123
```

Now I just need to know how to do the equivalent of the second command from within PHP.

Comment: I tried putting the same code on another Ubuntu server and I'm getting the same exact error. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Could be some php.ini setting or apache follow or openbasedir setting !

Comment: Okay. Any suggestions on how to narrow it down?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but the equivalent of

```
curl -v -sslv3 https://foo.com/OA_HTML/RF.jsp?function_id=123
```

is

```
$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); //set to force SSL3
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://foo.com/OA_HTML/RF.jsp?function_id=123");
$result = curl_exec ($ch);  //execute the request
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time CURL over SSL uses OpenSSL, more than likely either CURL or OpenSSL is not installed or enabled on the new server. Save a file on the server with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and check if these are enabled

---

### ADD

Either that or your SSL Certificates where not created on the machine you are trying to use them on. Each SSL certificate has specific information about each machine (if received from an online vendor)

Comment: cURL is definitely enabled on both servers. OpenSSL seems to be, although only the working server lists OpenSSL under "cURL Information". How do I make sure my SSL certificates are good? I've looked in `/etc/ssl/certs` but I don't know what I'm looking for. The non-working server has WAY more in that dir than the working server.

Comment: create a php file and add <?php phpinfo(); ?> to see if openssl is enabled on the servers not working. Was the non-working server used prior or is it a fresh install

Comment: Oh, in my previous comment I was referring to what I was seeing from `phpinfo()`. cURL is quite obviously installed and enabled but there's not a clear indicator for OpenSSL as far as I can tell. The server is a fresh install.